# Could someone check if these product and sum rule questions are correct?

Tags: counting, discrete-mathematics

Are these correct if not can I get an explanation thanks!

1) A string has the form 0???0, where each ? could be a 0 or a 1. How many possible strings are there? 
Would it be 6 possible strings?

2)Suppose a license plate number in this state can only contain capital​ letters and digits and can only be any string of the form: 
Letter-Letter-Letter-Digit-Digit-Digit-Digit 
How many different license plate numbers are possible?
Would it be 10^4⋅26^3 different license plates?

3)Suppose a license plate number in this state can only contain capital​ letters and digits and can only be any string of the form: 
Letter-Letter-Letter-Digit-Digit-Digit-Digit
How many license plate numbers are possible if no digit appears more than once?
Would it be 10⋅9⋅8⋅7⋅26^3

4) Suppose a license plate number in this state can only contain capital​ letters and digits and can only be any string of the form:
Either-Letter-Letter-Digit-Digit-Digit-Digit
where "Either" means it can be either Capital letter or digit.
How many different license plate numbers are possible?
Would it be (26+10)(26^2)(10^4)

Comment: 1) It should be 8 = 2³ = 2*2*2 because each `?` has 2 different possibilities.

Comment: Oh yah. How about the others?

Comment: They seem correct to me.